# How do I fix error "gs" ignored when using ghostcript for reducing pdf file size?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to reduce the filesize of a pdf using ghostscript. I found the command here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dPrinted=false -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf input_file_name.pdf
   **** Error 'gs' ignored -- ExtGState missing from Resources.
        Output may be incorrect.
```

I also executed the command without -dQUIIET and -dNOPAUSE, but that didn't clarify the problem:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 72.
Page 1
   **** Error 'gs' ignored -- ExtGState missing from Resources.
        Output may be incorrect.
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

I don't know what ExtGState means hence that I don't know what further steps are needed to solve the problem.

**EDIT1**

The command does put a PDF file out that is smaller. So it seems to work. I am simply unsure what the error means and whether it needs to be fixed and how.

adding `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` does not remove the error.

**Pdffonts**

```
pdffonts original.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
RLEATT+Aniron-Bold                   CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     11  0
JETQLW+CrimsonPro-Regular            CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     13  0
CZPFND+CormorantSC-Bold-Identity-H   CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     19  0
APXFPL+CrimsonPro-Italic             CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     74  0
VTLLQQ+CrimsonPro-Bold               CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    148  0
BCDEEE+Calibri                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     770  0
BCDFEE+MS-PGothic                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     774  0
BCDGEE+Wingdings-Regular             CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    778  0
BCDHEE+Calibri-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2816  0
CXSUEN+LMMono10-Regular-Identity-H   CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes   2888  0
BCDEEE+MinionPro-Regular             TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2899  0
BCDFEE+Aniron-Bold                   TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2904  0
BCDGEE+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2909  0
BCDHEE+MinionPro-Bold                TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2915  0
BCDIEE+MinionPro-Regular             CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes   2922  0
BCDJEE+TimesNewRomanPSMT             TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2929  0
BCDKEE+SymbolMT                      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes   2937  0
BCDLEE+ArialMT                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2946  0
BCDMEE+Aniron                        TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2955  0
BCDNEE+MinionPro-Bold                CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes   2968  0
BCDOEE+MinionPro-BoldIt              TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2978  0
BCDPEE+MinionPro-It                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    2983  0
BCEAEE+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no    3051  0
AJWSEY+CrimsonPro-BoldItalic         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes   3195  0
```

Comment: you've asked a few questions so far so you should by now know [ask] in ask ubuntu. OTOH, if the command you are using doesn't work, why not ask the question in Stack from the author of the reference you used since that may benefit others?

Comment: I was unsure why it said "gs" ignored while the command started with "gs". I therefore had the - probably - unrealistic thought that it doesn't know what it is while still executing the command to some degree. I guess you are right

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is highly related to another question.

Comment: ExtGState is mean a Extended Graphics State of XObject pdf itself, try to add `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` parameter to determines the compression level.

Comment: please check your object with `pdffonts original.pdf`, did you see the object section?.

Comment: I think I do. I updated my question to list them.